# Howto disable SSH local port forwarding?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, local

I have a server running Ubuntu and the OpenSSH daemon. Let's call it S1.

I use this server from client machines (let's call one of them C1) to do an SSH reverse tunnel  by using remote port forwarding, eg :

```
ssh -R 1234:localhost:23 login@S1
```

On S1, I use the default sshd_config file. From what I can see, anyone having the right credentials {login,pwd} on S1 can log into S1 and either do remote port forwarding *and* local port forwarding. Such credentials could be a certificate in the future, so in my understanding anyone grabbing the certificate can log into S1 from anywhere else (not necessarily C1) and hence create local port forwardings.

To me, allowing local port forwarding is too dangerous, since it allows to create some kind of public proxy. I'm looking for a way tto disable only -L forwardings.

I tried the following, but this disables both local and remote forwarding :

```
AllowTcpForwarding No
```

I also tried the following, this will only allow -L to SX:1. It's better than nothing, but still not what I need, which is a "none" option.

```
PermitOpen SX:1
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way, so that I can forbid all local port forwards to write something like :

```
PermitOpen none:none
```

Is the following a nice idea ?

```
PermitOpen localhost:1
```

Comment: so, as always, lets get to the root of this: what is your _real_ problem, why do you want to setup something like this for mobile /embedded devices, what do you want to solve?

Comment: The problem to be solved here is to be able to open a Telnet session, anywhere from the Internet, to a mobile/embedded device connected to the Internet, taking into account that the device might be NATed, or firewall'd, hence not reachable from the Internet.

Comment: telnet .. what for? for punching holes into firewall google for 'stun'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

anyone with login credentials can bring up their own instance of sshd, running on a random port and allow whatever they want, including -L local forwardings:

```
% /usr/sbin/sshd -d -f mysshd.config -p 12345
```

if you do not trust the users to do something with your machine then you shouldnt allow them to login in the first place.

(btw, the -D flag is kind of "proxy-problematic" as well)

Comment: Well I guess I can setup a very restrictive account for this purpose (eg. stick the user to its home, no listing, no filesystem browsing), so that it can not start and sshd (or install and start an sshd binary). The point is that the clients are supposed to be embedded devices. But since they will probably embedded certificates and their flash memoery can be dumped, it's possible the certificates will leak, hence allowing anyone to login to S1.

Comment: Using ChrootDirectory for that particular user will do the trick, will try that !

Comment: In authorized_keys, set `command="/sbin/nologin"`. This should prevent them from running any commands on the server.

Comment: The statement "anyone with login credentials can bring up their own <whatever>" is false. `ssh` can be used to connect to accounts which have severely restricted login shells that do not allow this. Port forwarding is a security hole in such restricted shells. In addition to running a permitted command, the user can create tunnels.

Comment: Quote from `sshd_config` man page: *Note that disabling TCP forwarding doesn't improve security **unless users are also denied shell access**, as they can always install their own forwarders.* (Emphasis mine).

Comment: Wonder if the answer lower down by Markus Rathgeb is even more complete: he suggests to give a nologin shell to the user, and to disable the local port forwarding only.

Comment: With a sufficiently restrictive firewall, you could block request to any unknown ports, so an external entity wouldn't be able to connect to that sshd server.

Answer (score 20):

Another solution would be to only allow port forwarding to specififc users:

From SSH: The definitive guide

Port forwarding can be globally enabled or disabled in sshd. This is done with the serverwide configuration keyword AllowTcpForwarding in /etc/sshd_config. The keyword may have the value yes (the default, enabling forwarding) or no (disabling forwarding):

```
# SSH1, SSH2, OpenSSH
AllowTcpForwarding no
```

In addition, SSH2 has the following options:

```
# SSH2 only
AllowTcpForwardingForUsers
AllowTcpForwardingForGroups
```

The syntax of these is the same as for the AllowUsers and AllowGroups options. [Section 5.5.2.1, "Account access control"] They specify a list of users or groups that are allowed to use port forwarding; the server refuses to honor port forwarding requests for anyone else. Note that these refer to the target account of the SSH session, not the client username (which is often not known).

...

It's important to realize that the directives in this section don't actually prevent port forwarding, unless you also disable interactive logins and restrict what programs may be run on the remote side. Otherwise, knowledgeable users can simply run their own port-forwarding application over the SSH session. These settings alone might be a sufficient deterrent in a nontechnical community, but they won't stop someone who knows what she's doing.

Comment: Basically I'll have only one user provisionned on S1. AFAIU, in this specific case, using AllowTcpForwardingForUsers/AllowTcpForwardingForGroups will not do the trick, right ? Forbidding interactive login is a good idea since it will make users not be able to start binaries. But any client will still be allowed to by using -L syntax right ? So for now, the best options would be : 1/ Disable interactive login, 2/ PermitOpen with a fake hostname:port. Did I miss something ?

Comment: The best way to verify this, would be to try the setup.

Comment: I cannot see these options in the free OpenSSH software. A google for `AllowTcpForwardingForUsers` reveals that it's configured in an `sshd2_config`, which is used in some commercial programs. See one of the answers to: http://superuser.com/questions/384643/what-is-difference-between-ssh-and-ssh2-directories

Comment: ^ OpenSSH has `Match` blocks in the configuration. You can `Match` on users and groups, and enclose the `AllowTcpForwarding` within.

Answer (score 6):

There is now an option to allow only local / remote forwarding.

> **AllowTcpForwarding**
>
> Specifies whether TCP forwarding is permitted.
> The available options are “yes” or “all” to allow TCP forwarding,
> “no” to prevent all TCP forwarding,
> “local” to allow local (from the perspective of ssh(1)) forwarding only or
> **“remote” to allow remote forwarding only**.
> The default is “yes”.
> Note that disabling TCP forwarding does not improve security unless users are also denied shell access, as they can always install their own forwarders.

So, as stated already you should set the shell to `nologin`, too.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this problem was to add:
**PermitOpen fo.local:80** in the main section of the sshd_config.

This simply denies any request of local forwarding besides fo.local:80.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a way tto disable only -L forwardings

If I understand you correctly, your users have full shell access, but you don't want them to be able to open connections towards the rest of the net.

The "local port forwarding" allowed by SSH is just one of the possible ways to do that. Others include launching an instance of `socat`, `netcat`, or any other number of tools.

The best way to control outgoing as well as incoming connections in Linux is Netfilter, aka IPTables.

It has a special module called owner (`ipt_owner`) which allows you to match various characteristics of the packet creator, for locally generated packets.  It is valid in the `OUTPUT` and `POSTROUTING` chains.

You can use it to deny outgoing packets generated by certain groups of users, thus disallowing any kind of port forwarding, not just the `-L` option of SSH.