# what is difference between .ssh and .ssh2 directories

Tags: ssh

Why I have both in home directory? Is this just different versiosn and one can be deletec?

When I generate SSH public/private key with program `ssh-keygen`, which is used?

Comment: What OS??  What version of SSH are you running?

Comment: @Zoredache: Ubuntu 11.04 and its default SSH

Comment: @Zoredache: how I know ssh version? `ssh -v` say `OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010`

Comment: That is the version.  Not sure why you would have a `.ssh2` folder.  OpenSSH by default will only use `.ssh`.

Answer (score 1):

There were two major versions of the SSH protocols: Version 1 and Version 2. Generally, the later versions of the software support both versions of the protocol (though I believe it is best practice to disable SSH version 1 support in the SSH daemon/sevice configuration).

The current version of the [ssh-keygen](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-keygen&sektion=1) program from OpenSSH typically generates keys (for SSH protocol 1 or 2) in a folder named .ssh

Some [commercial SSH](http://www.ssh.com/) [programs](http://support.attachmate.com/techdocs/1926.html) and apparently some [earlier versions of openssh](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/06/comprehensive-guide-for-ssh2-key-based-authentication-setup/) might use a .ssh2 folder.

Comment: But you can find a `sshd2_config` manual page online which lists more options that are not documented for `sshd_config` of OpenSSH. What is with that? For instance `AllowTcpForwardingForUsers`.

Comment: ^ Aha, OpenSSH has `Match` blocks in the configuration. You can `Match` on users and groups, and enclose the `AllowTcpForwarding` within to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether .ssh and .ssh2 are really directories and not files. Just checked the other day and the same entries in my system happened to be files that too malicious ones which were generating huge outbound traffic.