# Tunnel SSH over redirection server

Tags: networking, ssh, vnc, openssh, ssh-tunnel

If I am on the university network I can SSH into the machines with `ssh username@machine_name`. However when I am off the university network I have to `ssh username@ssh.university.edu`.

When I SSH to the `unversity.edu` address, it will automatically redirect me to a random machine (presumably for load balancing). Everything works fine except tunneling. I can tunnel (for example VNC connections) using `ssh -L 5900:localhost:5901 username@machine_name`, but tunneling over the university domain doesn’t work (e.g. `ssh -L 5900:localhost:5901 username@ssh.university.edu`).

How could I get the tunneling to work?

Comment: well one wrong thing for sure is you're missing the -L or -R.. tunneling requires -L or -R    When you do -L PORTA:IPB:PORTC  it means open PORTA on the local machine and forward to IPB:PORTC. When you do -R then it'd open PORTA on the remote machine and forward to IPB:PORTC on the local machine.  You haven't done either -L or -R

Comment: Oops I did use them. I will edit them in

Comment: I have no idea, maybe they disabled port forwarding http://superuser.com/questions/229743/howto-disable-ssh-local-port-forwarding   but it might help a bit if you do a lot of copy/pasting from cmd prompt showing that it's a different machine that you end up on. Also see if you can ssh directly to that machine.. You might be able to make a general enquiry to the tech department at your university and ask them (General enquiries, if allowed, often mean not having to give your name to them, though i guess you could give it in a regular enquiry and might not even have to give it)

Comment: I am pretty sure the ports are closed when using external access. Try comparing `nmap machine_name` with `nmap ssh.university.edu` where you should see port 5901 open on machine_name and closed on ssh.university.edu.