# How to disable local port forwarding only in SSH authorized_keys file?

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, sshd, authorized-keys

This question is related to this one, [here](https://superuser.com/q/229743/1218054), but the accepted answer for that question does not actually answer the question and is inaccurate, as pointed out in this [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/229743/howto-disable-ssh-local-port-forwarding#comment619992_229748).

Basically, I have a similar situation as the other post's author. I have an sshd server with password authentication disabled, and I sometimes need to open up a port on that server to proxy connections to a machine that lacks some tools that I need. I can accomplish this by executing the following command from the machine to which I want the connections forwarded.

```
$ ssh -nNTR 22122 user@sshd-server
```

This works fine, but I want to restrict incoming SSH connections to only open a remote listener on one particular port while disallowing local port forwards and shell commands. In other words, all the following commands should fail.

```
$ ssh user@sshd-server
$ ssh -nT user@sshd-server <any-command>
$ ssh -nNTL 22122:localhost:22122 user@sshd-server
$ ssh -nNTR 10000 user@sshd-server
```

Here is what I placed in my `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file to try to accomplish this, but it is currently preventing me from executing any of the above commands, including the one that I actually want to work.

```
restrict,command="/bin/false",permitlisten="localhost:22122" ssh-ed25519 ... user@kali
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As pointed out [here](https://superuser.com/a/829356/1218054), a possible solution is to set `AllowTcpForwarding` equal to `remote` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but I'd ideally like to set this option on a per-user / per-key basis, rather than globally.